# System Stack overflow exception Infinite loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am getting `System.Stack.Overflow.Exception` with a message:

> Make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion.

But I don't know what is wrong with this code.

```
    public string Projects()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
        {
            string htmlStr = "";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_oldprojects", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgenId", Session["AgencyId"].ToString());
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int ProjId = reader.GetInt32(0);
                string ProjTitle = reader["ProjTitle"].ToString();

                htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + ProjId + "</td>" +  ProjTitle + "<td><a href=\"OldProjView.aspx?pId=" + ProjId + "\" class=\"btn btn-small\" title=\"Detailed View\"><i class=\"icon-search\"></i></td>" + "</tr>";
            }

            return htmlStr;
        }
    }
```

[image: Image showing the problem]

Procedure for getting all projects

```
CREATE procedure sp_oldprojectsa 
@AgenId int
As 
Begin
Select * from OldProjects where AgencyId=@AgenId
End
```

Massage in Call Stack:
    [External Code] 
    The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded.

Comment: You are missing two `using` blocks and you should be using a `StringBuilder` for string concatenation in a loop. But I see no recursion or infinite loop. How many rows does your reader have?

Comment: Did you check your stored procedure itself, that it is not somehow the source of the problem?

Comment: `string ProjTitle = reader.GetInt32(1);` or what index it is

Comment: What line is the error occurring on? I'm not seeing anything that is consuming unlimited stack space here.

Comment: I doubt your are using recursion on Projects() function ... Are you trying to find Projects of Projects ?

Comment: nvoigt. There are 141 rows in total. I see this problem occurs when the row count exceeds from 80. if the record are bellow 80 then everything is fine.

Comment: @user3811350 Please show us the stack trace.

Comment: @Rob is correct, if there's a stack overflow problem, the primary way is check that what's in the call stack.

Comment: can you please post the code of the stored procedure `Sp_oldprojects` may be something wrong in it.

Comment: That screenshot makes it more clear than ever that the problem is *not* in the piece of code you've put at the top of your question. You need to at least find the actual piece of code where the error is, to give us a chance of answering. Also, side note, don't use `sp_` as a prefix for naming stored procedures. It's [not recommend by MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, you're just missing `reader.Close();` after your while loop.

```
 public string Projects()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        string htmlStr = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_oldprojects", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgenId", Session["AgencyId"].ToString());
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int ProjId = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string ProjTitle = reader["ProjTitle"].ToString();

            htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + ProjId + "</td>" +  ProjTitle + "<td><a href=\"OldProjView.aspx?pId=" + ProjId + "\" class=\"btn btn-small\" title=\"Detailed View\"><i class=\"icon-search\"></i></td>" + "</tr>";
        }
        reader.Close();
        return htmlStr;
    }
}
```

Have a look at [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) which will go through the DataReader.

Comment: Since OP know how to use `using statement`, and the `SqlDataReader` is disposable. How about use a `using statement` on reader?

Comment: Agreed @J.C, I was simply adding in the part that seemed to be missing. As for how it would solve the issue, I was assuming that not disposing of the reader would result in the `infinite recursion.` part of the OP's issue. Sorry user3811350, was hoping that was the answer. Was at my phone while posting so cannot test.